# jQuery .getJSON() poll memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, memory-leaks

I have a dashboard that presents some stats and until now it was quite static, i.e. if I wanted a fresh data I had to refresh the page. I have since moved to a more dynamic way with jquery to load stats on an interval. It works pretty good, I don't need to refresh the page anymore.

However, I noticed that if I leave the page open for some time the memory usage goes up and up with no signs of stopping.
It starts at about 50MB then in couple of hours (maybe only 1) saw it reach 1.2GB. Refreshing the page doesn't reclaim the memory!

And the obvious question... What am I doing wrong?

Samples:

```
@app.route("/getstats")
def getstats():
    return jsonify({'data': render_template('stats.html', stats=stats())})


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function poll() {
        var isMenuClosed = document.querySelector('.mdl-menu__container.is-visible') == null;
        if (isMenuClosed) {
            $.getJSON('/getstats',
                function(data) {
                    $("tbody#stats").empty().append(data.data);
                    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
                });
            $.getJSON('/getwidgets',
                function(wdata) {
                    $("div#widgets").empty().append(wdata.data);
                });
        }
        setTimeout(poll,5000);
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

*I have very limited knowledge on Python and especially JavaScript.*

Comment: Is this memory leak in the browser?

Comment: Yes, the browser. The flask/python service has no issues with memory.